# How to get the "this" from parent function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a simple tab system with angularjs, but I'm having trouble referring to `this` in the parent function. I know I might be misunderstanding some fundamentals, so please educate me:

js:

```
$scope.tabs = {
    _this: this, // doesn't work
    open: function(elem) {
        $scope.tabsOpen = true; 
        if(elem) 
            $scope[elem] = true;
    },
    close: function() {
        $scope.tabsOpen = false;    
    },
    about: {
        open: function() {
            $scope.aboutOpen = true;    

            _this.notification.close(); // doesn't work
            $scope.tabs.notification.close();  // works

        },
        close: function() {
            $scope.aboutOpen = false;   
        }           
    },
    notification: {
        open: function() {/*etc*/},
        close: function() {/*etc*/}
    },
    message: {
        open: function() {/*etc*/},
        close: function() {/*etc*/}
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:-

```
$scope.tabs = getTab();

function getTab(){
    var tab = {
        open: function(elem) {
            $scope.tabsOpen = true; 
            if(elem) 
                $scope[elem] = true;
        },
        close: function() {
            $scope.tabsOpen = false;    
        },
        about: {
            open: function() {
                $scope.aboutOpen = true;    
                tab.notification.close(); // Should work
             },
            close: function() {
                $scope.aboutOpen = false;   
            }           
        },
        notification: {
            open: function() {/*etc*/},
            close: function() {/*etc*/}
        },
        message: {
            open: function() {/*etc*/},
            close: function() {/*etc*/}
        },
    }

    return tab ;
}
```

This way you don't rely on what `this` context would be which is anyways determined by the execution context, not where it is defined. Here you are just using a local `tab` object created in the local scope while calling the function `getTab` and instead of doing `_this.notification.close();` you can just do `tab.notification.close();`, where `tab` is really the `this` that you are looking for there. [A simple Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aBxts5?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, this made a lot of sense!